# Weak property in a Swift protocol may only be a class or class-bound protocol type

Tags: swift, types, protocols, weak-references

I would like to define a protocol which is used in a Viper architecture to establish a connection between a Viper components using a protocol with a weak property but I get the following error message:

> 'weak' may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types,
>   not 'Self.ViperViewClass'

```
protocol ViperPresenter: class {

    associatedtype ViperViewClass
    weak var view: ViperViewClass! { get set }

}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Protocols can't currently require properties to be implemented as `weak` stored properties.

Although the `weak` and `unowned` keywords are currently allowed on property requirements, they have no effect. The following is perfectly legal:

```
class C {}

protocol P {
  weak var c: C? { get set }
}

struct S : P {
  var c: C? // strong reference to a C instance, not weak.
}
```

This was [filed as a bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-479), and [SE-0186](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0186-remove-ownership-keyword-support-in-protocols.md) will make the use of `weak` and `unowned` on property requirements in a protocol a warning in Swift 4.1 (in both Swift 3 and 4 modes), and an error in Swift 5.

But even if protocols *could* require properties to be implemented as `weak` or `unowned` stored properties, the compiler would need to know that `ViperViewClass` is a class type (i.e by saying
 `associatedtype ViperViewClass : AnyObject`).