# Swift generic protocol with weak property - 'weak' may only be applied to class bound protocols

Tags: ios, swift, generics, protocols, weak-references

Seeing what I believe is a bug in Swift with a generic based protocol. The protocol is below:

```
protocol Coordinated {
    associatedtype GenericCoordinatingDelegate: CoordinatingDelegate
    weak var coordinatingDelegate: GenericCoordinatingDelegate? { get set }
}

protocol CoordinatingDelegate: NSObjectProtocol { }
```

Xcode shows an error with this, however, claiming that `'weak' may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types, not Self.GenericCoordinatingDelegate`.

[image: Error]

Now, correct me if I'm wrong, but `GenericCoordinatingDelegate` is here constrained to the `CoordinatingDelegate` protocol type defined below, which is derived from `NSObjectProtocol`, hence constraining it to classes  only. Swift can see this and therefore should allow the `weak` modifier to be used on the property derived from it.

Can anyone see anything that I've missed or is this actually a bug in Swift?

**EDIT:**

Thank you for your suggestion, Hamish, I have edited my code to reflect this. However, I am now getting another strange issue.

```
class WelcomeIntroViewController: UIViewController, OnboardingViewController, TwoPartGradientLayerProvider, Coordinated {

    typealias GenericCoordinatingDelegate = WelcomeCoordinatingDelegate
    weak var coordinatingDelegate: GenericCoordinatingDelegate?
```

That is the implementation of the protocol as defined above, however, Swift claims that the view controller does not conform to the protocol, and tries to add another `typealias`. It will do this continuously, even with like 50 matching `typealias`es. Not sure what's going on here?

Comment: `= CoordinatingDelegate` provides the associated type with a default type, but it doesn't place any constraints on it. You would have wanted to say `associatedtype GenericCoordinatingDelegate : AnyObject = CoordinatingDelegate` or perhaps more likely what you were intending `associatedtype GenericCoordinatingDelegate : CoordinatingDelegate`. But note that the `weak` attribute in protocols has no effect anyway, compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/47699813/2976878.

Comment: @Hamish would you mind speculating on my edit?

Comment: What's `WelcomeCoordinatingDelegate`? Presumably it's a protocol that derives from `CoordinatingDelegate`? If that's the case, then you've run into the age old problem of [protocols not conforming to themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself/43408193#43408193) (i.e `WelcomeCoordinatingDelegate` doesn't conform to `CoordinatingDelegate` so cannot satisfy the associated type).

Comment: It's exactly that, yes. Thanks for the article, that was an interesting read and definitely provided some insight into the problem. I have managed to workaround the issue by annotating my protocols as `@objc`. Obviously this is not ideal, but it will do for now. By the sounds of things, they're working on improving the way Swift handles this anyway.